# Increasing Jenkins process priority?

Tags: c++, macos, jenkins, makefile, continuous-integration

When my C++ program build script is called from a Jenkins job, it takes far more time to be built. The CPU usage instead of being on 100% is on only taking 16%.

Of course I don't want Jenkins to fully occupy my computer rendering it unusable while doing a build but making it faster would be very useful.

I have installed Jenkins via brew on Mac OS.

Does anyone know how to change the priority of the Jenkins process so it's allowed to use more CPU while building?

Comment: How your question relates to C++?

Comment: You may appreciate using [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) to build your code. It's pretty good at utilizing available resources - and CMake can generate Ninja build files.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the question here is not the build system. I use Qt so I will need to stick with qmake. I'm just trying to create a continuous integration flow. Inside my build script I call make -j4 but it seems to be ignoring that directive completely. It seems that the fact the build script is called from Jenkins/Java process, is limiting the number of workers to one. If call the build script on the terminal it takes the CPU usage to 100% and builds the code in one fifth of the time. I'm really puzzled with this. Thanks!

Comment: "I use Qt so I will need to stick with qmake" - That is *not at all* a fact. The product I work on daily uses Qt and we use CMake (and Ninja) on both Windows, Linux and Mac. There's *no* requirement to use qmake just because you use Qt.

Comment: Can you check the amount of memory allocated to Jenkins JVM ? try increasing it.

Comment: @jesperJuhl sorry but the build system is not relevant in this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Following one of the comments suggestions I have decided to increase the heap size of the Java machine on the homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist file:

```
<string>-Xmx2048m</string>
```

And then call:

```
brew services stop jenkins
brew services start jenkins
```

The behaviour was the same so I decided to restart the machine and try again and now it is working as supposed. I'm not sure if this was a general glitch or if it was related with the Java heap size parameter.